# SQL - group session log entries and order the groups by session start time

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I am new to SQL, and could not find out how to make below query. Surely, I am missing a quite basic expression, but I was unable to find it myself.

I have below table, used to store application log entries. Each entry has a timestamp of recording, identifier of the application that made that entry, the action the application actually performed, and a unique ID for the given session of that application instance.

```
item_id  item_datetime      app action  session_id
1   2011-06-20 19:01:04     a   start   23B6C531-6D38-4E47-A887-10B945B48BD9
2   2011-06-20 19:01:05     b   start   7E6D0F55-4280-46DF-A829-F6821FF028D5
3   2011-06-20 19:03:45     b   job     7E6D0F55-4280-46DF-A829-F6821FF028D5
4   2011-06-20 19:09:33     a   job     23B6C531-6D38-4E47-A887-10B945B48BD9
5   2011-06-20 19:27:00     a   quit    23B6C531-6D38-4E47-A887-10B945B48BD9
6   2011-06-20 19:50:00     c   start   12345678-1234-4321-1234-109876543210
7   2011-06-20 19:50:01     c   quit    12345678-1234-4321-1234-109876543210
8   2011-06-20 19:50:22     b   quit    7E6D0F55-4280-46DF-A829-F6821FF028D5
```

In this example, there are 3 different applications "a", "b" and "c" executed simultaneously, each session overlapping the others. What I need is a list groupped by sessions, and the sessions (resulted groups) should be ordered by session start time.
For above example table, I expect below result:

```
item_id  item_datetime      app action  session_id
1   2011-06-20 19:01:04     a   start   23B6C531-6D38-4E47-A887-10B945B48BD9
4   2011-06-20 19:09:33     a   job     23B6C531-6D38-4E47-A887-10B945B48BD9
5   2011-06-20 19:27:00     a   quit    23B6C531-6D38-4E47-A887-10B945B48BD9
```

2   2011-06-20 19:01:05     b   start   7E6D0F55-4280-46DF-A829-F6821FF028D5
3   2011-06-20 19:03:45     b   job     7E6D0F55-4280-46DF-A829-F6821FF028D5
8   2011-06-20 19:50:22     b   quit    7E6D0F55-4280-46DF-A829-F6821FF028D5

6   2011-06-20 19:50:00     c   start   12345678-1234-4321-1234-109876543210
7   2011-06-20 19:50:01     c   quit    12345678-1234-4321-1234-109876543210

I tried group by with order by, but the problem is that the result's sorting is based on the alphabetical order of the session_id's - but this is not what I need, the sessions id's uniqueness is what matters, their "value" does not matter.

Comment: What do you mean by uniqueness of the session id, cos, when you use order by the values will be sorted, alphabetically, but then you'll achieve the desired result rt. ie the three session ids will be together, and then adding  time to the order by will sort your time

Comment: This is a table of MyISAM type on MySQL server.

Comment: @Balanivash, on uniqueness I mean: the value, or the alphabet order of the SID's do not matter in this case (I do not necessarily want to display the SID's), those should be only the base of groupping the entires. If I sort first by SID, then by date, then a session_id like AAAA-... would appear first, with its 3 entries together sorted by date. But the session AAAA-... might be 2 years old, so any alphabetical ordering based on SID is useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a subquery to find the first date a session was seen.  That allows you to order sessions:

```
select  yt.item_id
,       yt.item_datetime
,       yt.app
,       yt.action
,       yt.session_id
from    (
        select  session_id
        ,       min(item_datetime) as MinDate
        from    YourTable
        group by
                session_id
        ) sessions
left join
        YourTable yt
on      yt.session_id = sessions.session_id
order by
        session.MinDate
,       yt.item_datetime
```

Comment: This almost works. One strange behaviour is that it returns always "0" in session_id column (I can not see why). Second problem was that it listed only 1 entry per session. I modified it by adding **GROUP BY session_id** into the internal SELECT, like this:`  (
        select  session_id
        ,       min(item_datetime) as MinDate
        from    YourTable
        group by session_id
         ) sessions`

Comment: @cactusdev: You're right about the missing `group by`, I've added it to the answer.  No idea what could cause "0" to appear in the `session_id` columnn.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that you do not want grouping but only sorting no?
So :

```
SELECT item_id,item_datetime,app,action,session_id
FROM Table
ORDER BY app,item_datetime
```

Comment: Nope, this would sort the entries first by application. I have a table with around 10k entires by now, on which the above query applied, I would see on the first dozens of screen pages only entries for application "A". However, I would like to see the session entires, groupped into sessions (latest session shown first), and the entires sorted by date inside their relative session groups.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the clause

```
ORDER BY `session_id` ASC , `item_datetime` ASC
```

to your SQL qyery

Comment: This would alphabeticallt sort by session_id then by date, but a SID like AAAA-... that appear first, or even ZZZZ-... if that appear first, might have been recorded years ago. I need the latest session to appear first, with its entries listed in datetime sorted order.

Comment: then `order by item_datetime` and `group by session_id`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried anything like this?

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  yourTable
ORDER BY
  app,
  session_id,
  item_datetime
```

It would appear to be what you have described, though you say you've tried using just an ORDER BY?

Comment: This is not the one I need. It would alphabetically sort entried first by application name, then by... and here we can stop already: I need date-sorted list, groupped by session_id.